# Can I put properties inside of an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, properties

Can I put some properties inside an array like?

```
installments: string[];
```

I had already tried

```
installments: string[
    name: string;
    number: number
];
```

This is my interface

```
export interface FiscalDocumentData {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    number: number;
    type: string;
    company: string;
    provider: string;
    value: string;
    paymentCondition: string;
    checker: string;
    approver: string;
    product: string;
    issueDate: string;
    status: string;
    activity: string;
    comments: string;
    installments: string[];
  }
```

This is an example of a mock

```
this.data = [{
      id: "de89cbb7-be6c-49e7-b3d5-6eef106cca7b",
      name: "Linet Fawdrie",
      number: 83,
      type: "Audi",
      company: "Gigazoom",
      provider: "Crooks LLC",
      value: "$1.56",
      paymentCondition: "Peso",
      checker: "Eziechiele Beecraft",
      approver: "Randy Libri",
      product: "NITROGLYCERIN",
      issueDate: "10/10/2018",
      status: "approved",
      activity: "Support",
      comments: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      installments: ['1', '12-14-2019', '5000', 'Payed']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see all the values inside installments are string, so you need array of strings

```
installments: string[];
```

your Model should look like,

```
declare module namespace {

    export interface RootObject {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        number: number;
        type: string;
        company: string;
        provider: string;
        value: string;
        paymentCondition: string;
        checker: string;
        approver: string;
        product: string;
        issueDate: string;
        status: string;
        activity: string;
        comments: string;
        installments: string[];
    }

}
```

you can use **[JSON2TS](http://json2ts.com/)** to check

Comment: I forgot to share, but I had already tried too 
`installments: [number, string, number, string]`

I believe that works, but I need to name these properties, like:

`installments: [number: number, name: string, value: number, status: string]`
But this is not working

Comment: you dont need different data types as you have only strings

Comment: But when I will list this, I'm having difficulties, because of my code list all the installments[], and I can`t split them

Comment: I resolved my problem in an easier way, I made a PeriodicElementData on my component just to show the data...
When I need to implement the microservice, I believe that will be easy to apply this layout, Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

you can't add propeties to an array. only objects. but if you wand a array of some type of obejct try this:

```
installments: FiscalDocumentData[];
```